Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1130): Host is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
enter image description hereI tried to add some data to my Database which is on the server and I get this error

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1130): Host 'ххх .ххх.ххх ' is
not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in./.../..

The user was created through Cpanel and was granted all permissions.
Example code below:
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1130): Host 'ххх .ххх.ххх' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in

<?php
$servername = "xxx.xxx.xxx";
$username = "theveis1_nand1";
$password = "xxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "theveis1_userdata";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Error connect DB".$conn->connect_error); 

    }
?>

<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST"){
    include  "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/coments/connectDB.php";

    if ($conn === null) {
        die("Error connect DB");
    }

I'm a beginner, so I can't understand why this error (
Please help, explain the error and also help to fix it)
THANK YOU VERY MUCH in advance

https://www.knownhost.com/kb/how-to-connect-to-mysql-remotely-in-cpanel/

was granted all permissions...but was it granted permissions to connect from that IP address, specifically? Permissions in mysql and mariadb are host-based (the "host" being the IP or hostname of the machine which is trying to connect to the database)

P.S. If you're doing this on a shared host via CPanel there may also be a separate screen where you can enable remote connections to your database. Or the hosting provider may have disabled that capability. Contact your hosting company for support if you're unsure what your account allows.

That error message is not specific to the username. It means the entire machine is blocked.
